# Why was the colour of image changed in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I encountered a weird thing. The colour of my custom image was changed in the running app!
[image] The original colour of the alert bell image is red as shown. However, when the app runs, the colour of that bell changes to blue! [image]

The code to add the image is as follows:

```
UIImage *alertImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alert_bell"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:alertImage];
[imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
UIGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(disruptionsAlertAction:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
cell.accessoryView = imageView; // cell is a TableViewCell
```

I have idea what changed the colour if the bell and how to fix.

I would very much appreciate it if anyone can please explain this and let me know how I can fix it. Heaps of thanks!

Comment: In the asset catalog under the “rendering mode” for that image. Which option is selected! If it is selected as “template” then only the transparency of the image is used. The colour comes from the code. Change it to “original”

Comment: @Fogmeister Thank you for your comment. I did as you said. And it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set the rendering mode of the image view as **"UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal"**

```
UIImage *myIcon = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"alert_bell"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myIcon];
```

This could solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you, @Chintu. Thanks for your comment. I did as you said. It worked on my iPhone, but it still didn't work on the iPhone 14 Pro simulator. Strange thing! Fogmeister above provided an alternative solution which did work on both the real phone and the simulator.